# MongoDB query selecting documents with distinct fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine I have a MongoDB collection such as the following, where each row corresponds to a document:

```
{name:'rick', age:30}
{name:'john', age:40}
{name:'rick', age:35}
{name:'john', age:20}
{name:'jeff', age:50}
{name:'jeff', age:40}
```

Some documents have the "name" field set to the same value (2 ricks, 2 johns and 2 jeffs). If two or more documents have the "name" field set to the same value, of these I want to select only the document with the highest age. Like this:

```
{name:'rick', age:35}
{name:'john', age:40}
{name:'jeff', age:50}
```

Is there a rick aged 30 and a rick aged 35? I select rick aged 35! And so on...

But how can the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$name",sal:{$max:"$age"}}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

db.getCollection('Mytest').aggregate({$group:{_id:{"name":"$name"}, age: { $max: "$age" }}})

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "jeff"
    },
    "age" : 50
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "john"
    },
    "age" : 40
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "rick"
    },
    "age" : 35
}
```

Comment: But in the output I want the documents to be displaed as they are displayed in the database Therefore  I don't want {"_id":{"name" :"rick"},"age":35}  I want {name:'rick', age:35}